# What kind of wall bolt/anchor is removeable?

Tags: brick, bolts, anchor

What kind of wall bolt/anchor will allow me to remove and replace it as many times as necessary?

I am looking to attach a couple of 2x4's flat against a brick wall, however they would only stay there for a few weeks each year.  How can I fix them firmly to the wall in such a way that I can put them back each year using the same fixings?

I already have some expanding sleeve anchors if they would do.

(Nothing should be left sticking out of the wall when the wood is not there)

Comment: Thanks all :)  I'll go with the drop-in anchors as I can source those easiest at the local Screwfix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding sleeve anchors are probably not the best anchor to use for this - they use the bolt to secure the anchor in the hole.  Female drop in anchors would likely work much better, as they fasten independently of the bolt.

[image: drop in anchors]

Note that they require a setting tool (although some brands I've used include the set tool in the box of fasteners).

Answer (score 0):

You want to get wall anchors that look like this:

[image]

These are installed into a hole in the brick or concrete wall and would have the internally threaded end just below the surface of the wall. The hole size needs to be accurate and just the right depth. A hammer drill is recommended for making the hole.

Installing these does require a special tool that is used like this:

[image]

Once installed you use regular short stainless steel hex head bolts through holes in your 2x4's that thread into the flush anchors in the wall. You may want to use flat washers under the bolt heads to keep from splintering the wood as the bolts are tightened.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings Sparrow a good question.

Your sleeve-type anchors should probably work fine. Would not normally be our #1 choice. If the weight would be less than 100 pounds per anchor, you should be fine, just fill the hole as stated below.

A double acting anchor would be about the best for this type of application as it requires no setting tool and is less obtrusive to a wall application.
We use these anytime we anchor to a block or brick wall.

http://www.mcmaster.com/#double-expansion-anchors/=yu4jzo

You can locate the double acting anchors in a horizontal grout seam, their holding power is massive, even with a 1/4-20 bolt and you can easily re-use the hole time and time again.
Any open hole should have something to cover or fill it in 'off' times to keep out bugs, moisture and pesky children. A flat head stainless bolt usually works well.

The other two anchors, drop-in and wedge, are used primarily in floors or solid concrete walls.

Cheers,
Dean